# How to use vim editor in windows source insight

Tags: windows, vim, source-insight

I am using windows source insight. In this only the basic text editor is available. Is there any vim plugin available to use it in windwos source insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.sourceinsight.com/docs35/UserManual.pdf) (search for *ShellExecute*), you should be able to invoke a `ShellExecute` with an arbitrary program. If VIM is associated with a certain file as editor, this should work:

```
ShellExecute edit <yourfile>
```

If VIM is for some strange reason not the default editor for a certain file, you should try

```
ShellExecute "" C:/Path/to/vim.exe <yourfile>
```

Thay way, you should be able to call **any** external tool from Source Insight.

Answer (score 0):

add customer command in source insight and bind a new short key.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\gvim.exe"  --remote-silent +%l %f
```